# get url param from curly braces

Tags: php, string, url, strpos

I have this URL: `../foo::bar{2}233{13}171{1}1{20}0.html`

Parameters are in `{}`, values behind.

With this I'm able to get *one* parameter - despite the curly braces:

```
if (false !== strpos($url,'{2}')) {
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo 'error';
}
```

I want to get each value behind the `{}` .

Comment: Are keys and values always numeric?

Comment: yes, they are. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
$str = '../foo::bar{2}233{13}171{1}1{20}0.html';

$pattern = "/\{\d+\}/";

preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);

$prevStart = 0;
foreach($matches[0] as $match)
{
    $matchLen = strlen($match);
    $matchPos = strpos($str, $match, $prevStart);

    // Try to find the position of the next open curly brace
    $openCurlyPos = strpos($str, '{', $matchPos + $matchLen);

    // In case there is none found (.html comes up next), search for the . instead
    if($openCurlyPos === false)
        $openCurlyPos = strpos($str, '.', $matchPos + $matchLen);

    $length = $openCurlyPos - ($matchPos + $matchLen);

    $prevStart = $openCurlyPos;
    echo $match.': '.substr($str, $matchPos + $matchLen, $length).'<br />';
}

/*
Result:

{2}: 233
{13}: 171
{1}: 1
{20}: 0
*/
```

I know this way might be pretty redundant, but I have no idea how to do this using regex. This also seems simpler to figure out for people.

Comment: Thank you! Now I get all parameters.What do I have so add to get their values?

Comment: one more question: how can I get rid of the echoed curly braces

Comment: Just remove this part: `$match.': '.`

Comment: thanks, but I want the parameter to be echoed without the braces - e.g. `2 : 233` instead of `{2} : 233`

Comment: `preg_replace('/[\{\}]/', '', $match)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php. Try to find tutorials on Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Using `preg_match_all` you can extract the keys and values, here's a sample pattern to do so;

```
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match_all('/\\{(\\d+)\\}(\\d+)\\b/', '../foo::bar{2}233{13}171{1}1{20}0.html', $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

If we ignore the double escaping, it does as follows;

- Find a {
- 1 or more digits, until a }
- 1 or more digits, until a word boundary appears

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$pieces = explode("}", $str);
```

get all odd index elements.

```
$pieces[1],$pieces[3],$pieces[5]
```

etc...